# iText Java to Objective-c using j2objc

Tags: ios, itext, itextpdf, code-translation, j2objc

Has anyone tried with success translating or porting iText Java source code to Objective-c?

Is it possible at all ?

If not, how can one programmatically sign PDFs on ios?

Comment: Have you tried to port it to objective-c?

Comment: Xamarin and itextsharp may work.

Comment: @thelaws, it simply looks like requires terrifically big amount of time to port it _solo_, this is why i am asking here. i should look at xamarin next.

Answer (score 0):

It's not feasible to port iText to iOS using j2objc or RoboVM, since iText depends on Java AWT classes that neither project supports.

What might be more reasonable is to generate PDF files on a Java-based web server, then download them to your iOS device. This has the advantage of supporting Android devices without any PDF code.

Comment: iText **does not** depend on Java AWT. There is a version of iText, called [iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg) that was created for use on Android and GAE where Java AWT isn't supported either.

Comment: From consumer point of view its more convenient (_as thought secure_) to be able to sign PDF documents offline and, yes, its far from a trivial task :(

Comment: I based my comment by listing the imports in the iText open source. It's great to hear there's a portable alternative, but porting its SpongyCastle dependency sounds like a very big task.